# How can I load the source code of .php files using PHP?

Tags: php

I wanted to load the source code of a PHP file, so I tried to change the extension(.php) to .txt using rename like the following code:
`rename ($userpage, $userpage_no_extension.'.txt');`

I expected it shows the entire code of the file which is linked to `$userpage`, but when I execute
`$cont = fopen($userpage_no_extension.'.txt', 'w'); echo $cont;`
The result shows `Resource id #4`, which I don't even what it means. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: `file_get_contents("filename.php")` will get you the source code. There's no need to rename anything